# document.getElementBy(id?) depending on the input in html. Clickable gallery

Tags: javascript, arrays

The ultimate goal is to make a gallery (pure JS). Before doing that I'm trying a model. Two buttons, if you click #1 the string 1.jpg appear below, if you click #2 string 2.jpg appears. I want this to work in one function. What I have so far:

Javascript:

```
var imageData = new Array (2);
imageData[0]="1.jpg";
imageData[1]="2.jpg";


function gallery() {
var answer = document.getElementById("what").value;
document.getElementById("show").innerText = imageData[answer];
}
```

HTML:

```
    <button onclick="gallery()" id="what" value="1">1</button>
    <button onclick="gallery()" id="what" value="2">2</button>
    <div id="show"></div>
```

*So obviously I can't have 2 id's named "what".*
However, if I name the div that holds both of the buttons then nothing happens, I've tried using things like: `.class`, `getByName` etc. but somehow it doesn't work. What command should I use? Am I doing this the wrong way? Should I create some sort of array in html? How do you do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `this` as a parameter to the function, what this does it pass in the current object that you clicked on in the DOM. This way you don't even need to use id's:

```
<button onclick="gallery(this)" value="1">1</button>
<button onclick="gallery(this)" value="2">2</button>
```

Then in JavaScript you can say:

```
function gallery( item ) {
    var answer = item.value;
    ...
}
```